# Prometheus query to get the value of a metric since midnight or a dynamic offset

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am exporting a gauge metric named `order_count` to Prometheus and updating its value every 2 mins. I want to plot a Grafana graph about how many orders have been received since midnight of the same day.
I know the offset can be calculated by `time() % 86400` as in the number of seconds since midnight but prometheus does not accept dynamic offset values as follows

`order_count - order_count offset (time() % 86400)s`

How could I achieve the same. ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps grafana can provide time() % 86400?

Answer (score 1):

in your case you can do this with start() and using a time range of "today so far" for the time range of the graph

However there are a lot of other cases where calculating the offset would be extremely helpful - my team wants to have daily counts for "total past day" over a 7 day period and I am tearing my hair out trying to get it to offset always on the day, not relative to the current time.

Please allow calculations in offset!